# asp.net serialization issue on testing server

Tags: asp.net, session, serialization

I have been working on a project and it works fine on my development machine. When I move it to the stage server for testing I get the following error:

```
Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer'
```

The error message goes on to specify one of my business objects as the issue. The code was actually developed by another developer but I believe the issue is when a business object is saved into the session.

Why would that work on my local machine but not on the remote server?

Comment: Are u sure web.config is absolutely equal on both machines? if you use a state server all objects in the session MUST be serializable.

Comment: They are definitely not equal. Not even close. Is there a particular thing I should be looking for?

Comment: yes the session configuration. you should make sure all objects you put in the session are serializable or it wont work.

Comment: Is the object that you're serializing marked `Serializable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You development machine probably uses the InProc session provider which serializes onto memory. When the SQLServer session provider is used, there are are much stronger requirements on your objects.

Most probably - one of your objects is just not serializable. Reasons could vary, from simple "not marked as serializable" to "relying on external types which are not serializable".

Try to track down the problematic type by inspecting the inner exception. Usually you'll find a meaning information there.

Comment: Is there a way I can check to see if the InProc is being used? Unfortunately the server is a client machine so I don't have much control over it. I did find another article that gave some code I can use to test if my object is serializable so I'll be testing that when I get a chance.

Comment: The `sessionState` element of the `web.config` controls the way your data is persisted in the session container. Apparently it's configured to `InProc` or `SqlServer` on your client's machine. Ask him to change it to `InProc` temporarily to make sure that the problem is there and take some time to fix your objects so that they could be serialized. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(VS.71).aspx

Comment: I don't have a sessionState tag in my local web config. What would the default be?

Comment: The default is `InProc`, that's why the application works for you locally. The client could have probably changed this setting in his local web.config, server-level web.config or machineHost.config.

Comment: It would inherit from machine.config if no web config overrode it.

Comment: You were correct. Local was using InProc and the testing server was using SQLServer. I was able to set up my local machine to use SQLServer and duplicate the error.